# Number of precision digits for double in C++ different in windows and Linux. Why? Linux shows more than 20 non-zero precision digits

Tags: c++, c

Just did this:

```
double val1=numeric_limits<double>::max();
cout.precision(70);
cout<<"\nVal1: "<<val1;
```

In Windows I start getting 0s after 17 digits(16 digits after decimal point). However in Linux, as I keep increasing the cout.precision(NUMBER), more and more digits keep showing and they are not zeros.

Also, running the following code shows '15' on both Windows and Linux. Windows system is 32 bits and Linux one is 64 bit if that makes any difference.

```
typedef std::numeric_limits< double > dl;
cout << "\tdigits (decimal):\t" << dl::digits10 << endl;
```

Can any one help with an explanation as to what is going on here?
I thought number of precision digits will be same in Windows & Linux since sizeof(double) is 8 on both of them.

Comment: Are you using the same compiler? ie, `g++` for both.

Comment: In the interest of allowing us to repo what you're seeing - what's `SOME_BIG_VALUE`?

Comment: @Michael: Just changed the SOME_BIG_NUMBER, say let it be the maximum value of double.

Comment: @todda: Visual Studio in Windows, g++ on Linux

Comment: I think both MSC and g++ have options for controlling floating point precision (accuracy vs. speed). Perhaps you have different options on MSC than g++?

Comment: @todda: But "cout << "\tdigits (decimal):\t" << dl::digits10 << endl;" displays "15" on both the systems. Shouldn't this give the number of digits inside double? Seems to be working in Windows, not on Linux.

Answer (score 9):

When you print out a `double`, you often have to print out many, many digits before you print out the exact value of the `double`.  It is possible to print out a `double` exactly.  For example, the `double` closest to 1/3 has the value:

```
0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
```

Printing out this value exactly requires 54 digits past the decimal point.  But people say a `double` only has **about** 16 digits of precision.  What gives?

When you say that a double has 16 digits of precision, that means that you need at least 16 digits to make the double survive a round trip.  That is, the following process preserves the input data:

```
double -> 16 digit decimal -> double
```

So the extra digits past 16 aren't necessarily *garbage*, they're just unnecessary.  And according to the standard, they can be almost anything -- as long as reading the result will give you the same `double` back.

**The Summary:** My guess is that your standard library on Linux is printing out the exact value of the double, and the Windows library is truncating the result.  Both actions are permitted by the standard.

You almost certainly don't need the exact value of a double anyway, since arithmetic on floating point numbers is usually inexact.

Comment: So, I can safely discard(or treat as garbage) anything after the 15th digit after the decimal. Since it may not be guaranteed to be preserved in each calculation. Only the 15 digits after the decimal point are guaranteed to be operated upon in any operation?

Comment: @gandalf: A double doesn't have decimal digits, *period*.  Each individual operation guarantees a certain error, often expressed in terms of ULP, and some operations are "correctly rounded" as if they were done with infinite precision and then rounded to a double.  But if you combine a few operations together the accuracy can drop to zero.  (It's complicated, which is why they teach courses on floating point numbers.)

Comment: @gandalf: For example, if it really were 16 digits, you could compute `(0.3 - 0.2) * 10` and get 1.  You only need *one* measly digit of precision to get that equation correct.  However, you'll get a different answer if you use double precision numbers.

Comment: @gandalf34, you can rely on 15 digits after a *single* operation, but errors add up. For example if you start with 1e16 and add 1 to it 1e16 times, the result should be 2e16 - but it's likely to be 1e16 instead. As Dietrich says it gets complicated.

Comment: @Dietrich: Did the (0.3-0.2)*10 expression. Got:
0.9999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
I understand that double loses precision in trying to fit decimal numbers in binary in memory. But what I intend to make clear to myself is that anything after the 15th place of decimal is certainly not to be considered as reliable, even though it might be correct(closer) representation of the decimal number. Correct?

Comment: P.S. I prefer the representation with trailing zeros. If the original value was a decimal number, which happens far more often than chance, the trailing zeros are actually accurate. If they aren't accurate, such as the 1.0/3.0 example, they give a good hint to the human interpreting the output that truncation has taken place.

Comment: @Dietrich, Also the standard specifies that only the 15 places after the decimal one are to be regarded? So everything else can be neglected however correct or closer it might be.

Comment: @Mark, Your PS post: Exactly my feeling. Much more cleaner implementation of the standard. Gets confusion out of the way.

Comment: @gandalf: The standard lets implementations play loose with the digits printed out after the first 16 or so.  However, under carefully controlled circumstances, those digits could be entirely accurate.  Under most circumstances, you almost certainly have less than 16 digits of precision -- and you can have much less than 16.  The only guarantee is that when you print a number out with enough digits you can read it back in and get the same result -- even if that result is wrong.

Comment: @Dietrich, So accepting the fact that double can never represent decimal values 100% precisely due to binary storage, the other thing to keep in mind with this fact is that digits after 15th one are not to be treated as important. That is my understanding from this discussion. Correct me if I am wrong. Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 8):

Once you get past the number of digits contained in a double, you're at the mercy of your compiler's library implementation. Different algorithms for converting from binary to decimal will result in different output. Neither can be more accurate than the other.

Comment: Does this mean that 16th digit after decimal point is garbage in Linux? Because cout<<dl::digits10 shows 15 on both Windows and Linux. But on windows I start seeing zeros beyond 16th place after decimal, but on Linux the digits continue.

Comment: @gandalf34, that's exactly right - the extra digits are garbage. Prove it to yourself by ouputting a number with a known repeating value such as 1.0/3.0.

Comment: Yes, (1.0/3.0) shows:
0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
So the extra digits seem to be garbage. Also, can you tell why when cout<<dl::digits10 shows 15, but the number of digits after the decimal point are being shown 16 correctly? Is it that only upto 15 are to be considered reliable and the 16th one is for internal use only?
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mark, gandalf: Those digits are not garbage, they are the exact value of the `double` closest to 1/3.  Errors are introduced by the division, not by printing (in this case).

Comment: @gandalf34, there's not a strict mapping from the number of binary digits to the number of decimal digits, it's approximate. The 16th digit might be reliable if the leading digit is small enough. You could also get lucky and the 16th digit is correct just by coincidence.

Comment: @Dietrich, "exact" and "accurate" are two different concepts. The result may not be random, but it's not useful either. I'm trying to simplify things to make a point.

Comment: @Mark: I'm just saying that the IO *can* be accurate past the 16th digit, whereas the division can't.

Comment: @Mark, So I should just conclude that only digits up to the 15th one are to be regarded as results of a calculation or the value of a double. Since that seems to be the intention of double. Everything else is a matter of luck, it may be correct or may be not.

Comment: @gandalf34: No, that's wrong. The results of a calculation gave you 64 bits, not 15 digits. Computers calculate in binary. You can then in a second step convert those 64 bits to a decimal number. In both steps you may lose some precision depending on the input.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia entry on double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) defines the bounding errors for translation between decimal digits and double values very succinctly:

> This gives from 15 - 17 significant decimal digits precision. If a
>   decimal string with at most 15 significant decimal is converted to
>   IEEE 754 double precision and then converted back to the same number
>   of significant decimal, then the final string should match the
>   original; and if an IEEE 754 double precision is converted to a
>   decimal string with at least 17 significant decimal and then converted
>   back to double, then the final number must match the original.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have installed g++ 32 bit version on windows, and 64 bit on linux.
Just verify the program you are running, if it's 32 or 64 bit (you can check it by watching in task manager)

Comment: The size of a `double` is 64 bits even with a 32-bit library.