# The Beasley-Springer-Moro Algorithm in C++

Tags: c++

I have this Pseducode for the Beasley-Springer-Moro Algorithm:

[image: Pseudocode]

I wrote up this algorithm in C++, it runs fine but I believe there is something wrong in my C++ code. Here is my C++ code:

```
double *Beasley_Springer_Moro(int n, double u[]){
    double y[n];
    double r[n];
    double *x = new double[n];
    // Constants needed for algo
    double a_0 = 2.50662823884;     double b_0 = -8.47351093090;
    double a_1 = -18.61500062529;   double b_1 = 23.08336743743;
    double a_2 = 41.39119773534;    double b_2 = -21.06224101826;
    double a_3 = -25.44106049637;   double b_3 = 3.13082909833;

    double c_0 = 0.3374754822726147; double c_5 = 0.0003951896511919;
    double c_1 = 0.9761690190917186; double c_6 = 0.0000321767881768;
    double c_2 = 0.1607979714918209; double c_7 = 0.0000002888167364;
    double c_3 = 0.0276438810333863; double c_8 = 0.0000003960315187;
    double c_4 = 0.0038405729373609;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        y[i] = u[i] - 0.5;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(fabs(y[i]) < 0.42){
            r[i] = y[i]*y[i];
            x[i] = y[i]*(((a_3 * r[i] + a_2)*r[i] + a_1)*r[i] + a_0)/((((b_3 * r[i] + b_2)*r[i] + b_1)*r[i] + b_0)*r[i] + 1.0);
        } else{
            r[i] = u[i];
            if(y > 0){
                r[i] = 1 - u[i];
            }
            r[i] = log(-log(r[i]));
            x[i] = c_0 + r[i]*(c_1 + r[i]*(c_2 + r[i] *(c_3 + r[i] * (c_4 + r[i] * (c_5 + r[i]*(c_6 + r[i] * (c_7 + r[i]*c_8)))))));
            if(y < 0){
                x[i] = -x[i];
            }
        }
    }
    ofstream myfile ("bb.txt");
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        myfile << x[j] << ";" << endl;
    }
    return x;
}
```

If someone could just check to see if my C++ code looks correct that would be greatly appreciated. The reason I think it is wrong is because when I perform the Anderson-Darling statistic on the x value that the algorithm above returns I get a result that I believe must be wrong. So my suspicion is that I did something wrong in my code.

For completeness I will post my whole code here (I casted everything to long doubles but I still get the same results):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

long double *Box_Muller(int n, long double u[]);
long double *Beasley_Springer_Moro(int n, long double u[]);
long double Anderson_Darling(int n, long double X[]);
long double phi(long double x);


int main(){
    int n = 2000;

    // Mersenne Twister
    long double Mersenne[n];
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 e2(1);
    uniform_real_distribution<long double> dist(0, 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        Mersenne[i] = dist(e2);
    }

    // Poor LCG
    long double x[n];
    x[0] = 1.0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        x[i] = fmod(1229.0*x[i - 1] + 1.0, 2048.0);
    }
    long double u[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        u[i] = x[i]/2048.0;
        //cout << "u: " <<  u[i] << endl;
    }



    // Print Anderson Statistic for Mersenne 6a
    //long double *result = new long double[n];
    //result = Box_Muller(n,Mersenne);
    //Anderson_Darling(n,result);

    // Print Anderson Statistic for poor LCG 6b
    //long double *result1 = new long double[n];
    //result1 = Box_Muller(n,u);
    //Anderson_Darling(n,result1);

    // Print Anderson Statistic for Mersenne 7
    //long double *result2 = new long double[n];
    //result2 = Beasley_Springer_Moro(n, Mersenne);
    //Anderson_Darling(n,result2);

    // Print Anderson Statistic for poor LCG 7
    long double *result3 = new long double[n];
    result3 = Beasley_Springer_Moro(n, u);
    Anderson_Darling(n,result3);




    return 0;
}

long double *Box_Muller(int n, long double u[]){
    long double *X = new long double[n];
    long double Y[n];
    long double R_2[n];
    long double theta[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        R_2[i] = -2.0*log(u[i]);
        theta[i] = 2.0*M_PI*u[i+1];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        X[i] = sqrt(-2.0*log(u[i]))*cos(2.0*M_PI*u[i+1]);
        Y[i] = sqrt(-2.0*log(u[i]))*sin(2.0*M_PI*u[i+1]);
    }
    return X;
}

long double *Beasley_Springer_Moro(int n, long double u[]){
    long double y[n];
    long double r[n];
    long double *x = new long double[n];
    // Constants needed for algo
    long double a_0 = 2.50662823884;        long double b_0 = -8.47351093090;
    long double a_1 = -18.61500062529;   long double b_1 = 23.08336743743;
    long double a_2 = 41.39119773534;    long double b_2 = -21.06224101826;
    long double a_3 = -25.44106049637;   long double b_3 = 3.13082909833;

    long double c_0 = 0.3374754822726147; long double c_5 = 0.0003951896511919;
    long double c_1 = 0.9761690190917186; long double c_6 = 0.0000321767881768;
    long double c_2 = 0.1607979714918209; long double c_7 = 0.0000002888167364;
    long double c_3 = 0.0276438810333863; long double c_8 = 0.0000003960315187;
    long double c_4 = 0.0038405729373609;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        y[i] = u[i] - 0.5;
        if(fabs(y[i]) < 0.42){
            r[i] = y[i]*y[i];
            x[i] = y[i]*(((a_3 * r[i] + a_2)*r[i] + a_1)*r[i] + a_0)/((((b_3 * r[i] + b_2)*r[i] + b_1)*r[i] + b_0)*r[i] + 1.0);
        }
        else{
            r[i] = u[i];
            if(y[i] > 0){
                r[i] = 1 - u[i];
            }
                    r[i] = log(-log(r[i]));
                    x[i] = c_0 + r[i]*(c_1 + r[i]*(c_2 + r[i] *(c_3 + r[i] * (c_4 + r[i] * (c_5 + r[i]*(c_6 + r[i] * (c_7 + r[i]*c_8)))))));
            if(y[i] < 0){
                x[i] = -x[i];
            }
        }
    }
    ofstream myfile ("bb.txt");
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        myfile << x[j] << ";" << endl;
    }
    return x;
}

long double phi(long double x){
    return 0.5 * erfc(-x * M_SQRT1_2);
}

long double Anderson_Darling(int n, long double X[]){
    sort(X,X + n);
    // Find the mean of X
    long double X_avg = 0.0;
    long double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sum += X[i];
    }
    X_avg = ((long double)sum)/n;


    // Find the variance of X
    long double X_sig = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        X_sig += (X[i] - X_avg)*(X[i] - X_avg);
    }
    X_sig /= (n-1);


    // The values X_i are standardized to create new values Y_i
    long double Y[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        Y[i] = (X[i] - X_avg)/(sqrt(X_sig));
        //cout << Y[i] << endl;
    }

    // With a standard normal CDF, we calculate the Anderson_Darling Statistic
    long double A = -n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        A +=  -1.0/(long double)n *(2*(i+1) - 1)*(log(phi(Y[i])) + log(1 - phi(Y[n - 1 - i])));
    }
    cout << A  << endl;
}
```

Comment: Except that `double y[n];` is not standard C++ (VLA usage), Your algo implementation seems match the algo.

Comment: @Jarod42 so in other words my code looks fine?

Comment: @arash I casted them to long doubles so it should be fine no?

Comment: @arash I see your point, so what do you suggest I do?

Comment: nevermind, I was wrong. look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950738/number-of-precision-digits-for-double-in-c-different-in-windows-and-linux-why)

Comment: @arash I looked there but I don't know what to do, suggestions?

Comment: I would try to go through it step by step (with lots of printf). This types of codes are hard to debug.

Comment: `long double *result3 = new long double[n]; result3 = Beasley_Springer_Moro(n, u);` does memleak, simply do `long double *result3 = Beasley_Springer_Moro(n, u);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for the suggestion but I still get the same result that I know is wrong

Comment: @arash I tried to do that too, setting n = 2 and there is nothing wrong I did the math by hand

Comment: For which input, result is incorrect ?

Comment: so with the result3 you suggested what we are doing in this program is testing whether the x values from the Beasley algorithm is indeed standard normal cdf which is that the anderson darling test computes, but before we use the beasley algorithm we use a poor LCG, thus the @Jarod42 anderson darling test should indicate that we reject the null but with the result I am getting it is suggesting that I fail to reject and conclude that the data x follows a standard normal cdf when it does not, hope that makes sense

Comment: Weren't you getting the correct solution for Anderson yesterday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug in your code is here -

```
if(y<0)
```

and

```
if(y>0)
```

I think you mean to compare y[i].
Comparing y compares the address of the first element of the array, which is always going to be > 0.

Comment: Thanks, could you check this out I think its pretty easy but I cant seem to figure it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559603/deleting-an-element-in-eigen-library

Comment: Note that this can be done in the vector class not in the Eigen library I can simply convert it'